# How to create a flexible background image with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to set up my H1 tags with an expanding background-image, that serves as a "lower border" for the title, similar to this:
[image: Image of text saying, Literary Works & Legacy, with several thin lines below it, one of which curls at the ends. A dotted line extends vertically from the middle of the last line.]

Here is the fiddle I am working with:

https://jsfiddle.net/gq4b7vu4/

```css
#logoBuild {
    width: auto;
    border: 1px solid #F500FD;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #958a68;
    font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: table!important;
    background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottomborder.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
}


}
#titleBottom {
    border: 2px solid #0FEEF1;
}
#leftBottom {
    width: 48px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_left.png");
    background-repeat: none;
    border: 0px solid #F20004;
    float: left;
}
#rightBottom {
    width: 48px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_right.png");
    background-repeat: none;
    border: 0px solid #F20004;
    float: left;
}
#centerBottom {
    background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottomborder.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
}
#descenderBottom {
    background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_descender.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
    width: 1px;
    height: 27px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pageHead">
  <div id="logoBuild">
    <h1>Title goes here</h1>
    <div id="titleBottom">
      <div id="leftBottom"></div>
      <div id="centerBottom"></div>
      <div id="rightBottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    <div id="descenderBottom"></div>

  </div>
```

I need the graphic to expand according to the width of the title, with the end flourishes on either side and the descender beneath it.

I've tried to build the border after (separate from) the H1 declaration, and I tried placing the H1 inside of the `centerBottom` div, both to no avail.

Comment: Use an SVG. Much simpler

Comment: But wouldn't I have to use an SVG in proportional scale? For example, if the titles are "LITERARY WORKS" and "ABOUT", those would have variables widths, so the center "piece" would be a different width in each case. So I wouldn't be able to scale the design proportionally.

Comment: You can scale SVG in several ways...

Comment: You're creating a custom border, so use CSS `border-image` and `border-bottom`.

Answer (score 2):

Well this was a lot of fun

https://jsfiddle.net/gq4b7vu4/3/

Changed many of your styles to just psuedo content selectors.

```css
#pageHead { overflow: visible; }

.logoBuild { 
  display: block; 
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  min-height: 75px;
  margin: 0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 color:#958a68;
 font-family: 'Cantarell', sans-serif;
 text-transform:uppercase;
  background-image: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottomborder.png");
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-position: 0 48px;
  overflow: visible;
}

h1 img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 68px;
  left: 50%;
}

h1::before {
  position:absolute;
  left:-48px;
  bottom: 0;
  content: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_left.png");
}

h1::after {
 position: absolute; 
 right: -48px;
 bottom: 0;
 content: url("http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_right.png");
}
```

```html
<div id="pageHead">
  <div class="logoBuild">
    <h1>
      Title goes here
      <img src="http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_descender.png" alt="" class="bottom-center-brdr">
    </h1>
  </div>  
  <div class="logoBuild">
    <h1>
      Oh hey another cool one
      <img src="http://69.195.124.96/~scottar4/wp-content/themes/fscottfitzgerald/images/header/fscottfitzgerald_title_bottom_descender.png" alt="" class="bottom-center-brdr">
    </h1>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Things to note, min-height on that h1. You'll also need some bottom margin added to that header tag. There's an inline image in the header tag, didn't see an easy way to get around that, but assuming it could be implemented through more psuedo selectors and or a non-block element.

Comment: Could be cleaned up even more tbh